# LEFT OUTER JOIN...with differing matching keys

Tags: mysql, sql

So...this is a little confusing. I have 2 tables, one is basically a list of Codes and Names of people and topics and then a value, for example:

[image]

The second table is just a list of topics, with a value and a "result" which is just a numerical value too:

[image]

Now, what I want to do is do a `LEFT OUTER JOIN` on the first table, matching on topic and value, to get the "Result" field from the second table. This is simple in the majority of cases because they will almost always be an exact match, however there will be some cases there won't be, and in those cases the problem will be that the "Value" in table 1 is lower than all the Values in table 2. In this case, I would like to simply do the JOIN as though the Value in table 1 equalled the lowest value **for that topic** in table 2.

To highlight - the `LEFT OUTER JOIN` will return nothing for Row 2 if I match on topic and value, because there's no Geography row in table 2 with the Value 30. In that case, I'd like it to just pick the row where the value is 35, and return the Result field from there in the JOIN instead.

Does that make sense? And, is it possible?

Much appreciated.

Comment: There is not an exact match for `Mathematics`, but in that case the value in `table1` isn't lower than all the values in `table2` ... what do you want to do then?

Comment: @DavidFaber I messed up my first table - they should match. I'll edit the post, sorry for the confusion.

Comment: Are topics similar to subjects?

Comment: @Strawberry so similar that they are, in fact, exactly the same :P

Comment: And that doesn't strike you as odd or irritating?

Comment: Not in the slightest. This isn't my actual data, I just through it together so I could post up an example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Cross Apply here. There may be a better solution performance wise.

```
declare @people table(
Code int,
Name varchar(30),
Topic varchar(30),
Value int
)

declare @topics table(
[Subject] varchar(30),
Value int,
Result int
)

INSERT INTO @people values (1, 'Doe,John', 'History', 25),
(2, 'Doe,John', 'Geography', 30),
(3, 'Doe,John', 'Mathematics', 45),
(4, 'Doe,John', 'Brad Pitt Studies', 100)

INSERT INTO @topics values ('History', 25, 95),
('History', 30, 84),
('History', 35, 75),
('Geography', 35, 51),
('Geography', 40, 84),
('Geography', 45, 65),
('Mathematics', 45, 32),
('Mathematics', 50, 38),
('Mathematics', 55, 15),
('Brad Pitt Studies', 100, 92),
('Brad Pitt Studies', 90, 90)

SELECT p.Code, p.Name,
case when p.Value < mTopic.minValue THEN mTopic.minValue
    else p.Value
END, mTopic.minValue
FROM @people p
CROSS APPLY 
(
SELECT [Subject], 
    MIN(value) as minValue
FROM @topics t
WHERE p.Topic = t.Subject
GROUP BY [Subject]
) mTopic
```

I am also assuming that:

**This is simple in the majority of cases because they will almost always be an exact match, however there will be some cases there won't be, and in those cases the problem will be that the "Value" in table 1 is lower than all the Values in table 2.**

is correct. If there is a time when Value is not equal to any topic values AND is not less than the minimum, it will currently return the people.value even though it is not a 'valid' value (assuming topics is a list of valid values, but I can't tell from your description.)

Also technically you only need that case statement in the select statement, not the following mTopic.minValue but I thought the example showed the effect better with it.

Comment: Hi @david-jacobsen

Apologies for stupid edits, apparently I'm not allowed to press the return key -_-. Anyway...I'm confused as to how this works exactly...how does the CASE and the CROSS APPLY work together such that if, for example, we're considering a "Geography" row in Table one the CASE checks the minimum value for the "Geography" group created by the CROSS APPLY?

EDIT AGAIN: Never mind, I'm an idiot, it says it plain as day in your example. Thank you, I'll try that.

Comment: Mr @david-jacobsen, you are a gentleman and a scholar. That hurt my brain but seems to work perfectly, many thanks indeed.

Comment: I was just going to reply to your comment that I was afraid it wouldn't work. My chrome tab says this is MySQL - LEFT OUTER JOIN... and I don't believe MySQL has cross apply! I'm glad it worked for you. The short gist of it, is that a cross apply lets you use fields from the left hand table within the query on the right hand side, which gets us the minimum value.

Answer (score 0):

In this case I would make two joins instead of one. Something like this:

```
select * 
from Table1 T1 
LEFT JOIN Table2 T2 on T1.Topic=T2.subject and T1.Value=T2.VALUE 
LEFT JOIN Table2 as T3 on T1.Topic=T3.Subject and T1.Value<T2.Value
```

The do a case to choose the table to take values from. If T2.value is null then use T3.Value ELSE T2.Value. Hope this helps you

Answer (score 0):

Another method of performing this is by using a temporary table to hold the different values.
First insert the exact matches, then insert the non-exact matches that where not found in the initial select and finally grab all the results from the temp table. This solution is more code than the other, so just adding it as an alternative.

Example ([SqlFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/260329/1)):

Schema first

```
create table students
     ( code     integer,
       name     varchar(50),
       topic    varchar(50),
       value    integer );

create table subjects
     ( subject  varchar(50),
       value    varchar(50),
       result   integer );

insert students
     ( code, name, topic, value )
values
     ( 1, 'Doe, John', 'History',           25),
     ( 2, 'Doe, John', 'Geography',         30),
     ( 3, 'Doe, Jane', 'Mathematics',       45),
     ( 4, 'Doe, Jane', 'Brad Pitt Studies', 100);

insert subjects
     ( subject, value, result )
values
     ( 'History',           25,  95 ),
     ( 'History',           30,  84 ),
     ( 'History',           35,  75 ),
     ( 'Geography',         35,  51 ),
     ( 'Geography',         40,  84 ),
     ( 'Geography',         45,  65 ),
     ( 'Mathematics',       45,  32 ),
     ( 'Mathematics',       50,  38 ),
     ( 'Mathematics',       55,  15 ),
     ( 'Brad Pitt Studies', 100, 92 ),
     ( 'Brad Pitt Studies', 90,  90 );
```

The actual SQL query:

```
-- Temp table to hold our results
create temporary table tempresult
     ( code         integer,
       name         varchar(50),
       topic        varchar(50),
       studentvalue integer,
       subjectvalue integer,
       result       integer );

-- Get the exact results
insert tempresult
     ( code,
       name,
       topic,
       studentvalue,
       subjectvalue,
       result )
select stu.code,
       stu.name,
       stu.topic,
       stu.value as 'student_value',
       sub.value as 'subject_value',
       sub.result
  from students stu
         join
       subjects sub on sub.subject = stu.topic
                   and sub.value   = stu.value;

-- Get the non-exact results, excluding the 'students' that we already
-- got in the  first insert
insert tempresult
     ( code,
       name,
       topic,
       studentvalue,
       subjectvalue,
       result )    
select stu.code,
       stu.name,
       stu.topic,
       stu.value as 'student_value',
       sub.value as 'subject_value',
       sub.result
  from students stu
         join
       subjects sub on sub.subject = stu.topic
                       -- Business logic here: Take lowest subject value that is just above the student's value
                   and sub.value   = (select min(sub2.value)
                                        from subjects sub2
                                       where sub2.subject = stu.topic
                                         and sub2.value   > stu.value)
 where not exists (select 1
                     from tempresult tmp
                    where tmp.code  = stu.code
                      and tmp.name  = stu.name
                      and tmp.topic = stu.topic)

-- Get our resultset
select code,
       name,
       topic,
       studentvalue,
       subjectvalue,
       result
  from tempresult
 order by code,
          name,
          topic,
          studentvalue,
          subjectvalue,
          result
```

Answer (score 0):

A left join is not called for in the requirements. You want to join when T1.Subject = T2.Topic and then either when T1.Value = T2.Value or when T1.Value < T2.Value and T2.Value is the smallest value. Just write it out that way:

```
select  p.*, t.Result
from    @People p
join    @Topics t
    on  t.Subject   = p.Topic
    and(    t.Value     = p.Value
        or(     p.Value < t.value 
            and t.Value =(
            select  Min( Value )
            from    @Topics
            where   Subject = t.Subject )));
```

Which generates:

```
Code Name     Topic             Value Result
---- -------- ----------------- ----- ------
1    Doe,John History           25    95
2    Doe,John Geography         30    51
3    Doe,John Mathematics       45    32
4    Doe,John Brad Pitt Studies 100   92
```